# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory occasionally

Tags: python, nosuchfileexception

I have a web app and a mobile app that connect to my server. In my server I have a module (md.py) that uses another module (config.py) which reads data from a local XML file.

When I send a request to config.py (indirectly) for data from my apps everything works fine. The problem occurs when I call config.py from md.py which are both on the same machine.

This is the hierarchy:

```
root/
  start.py

  md/
    __init__.py
    md.py

  server/ 
    __init__.py
    config.py
    server.py

    data/
        config.xml
```

This is `md.py`

```
from server import config

class Md:

    def get_data(self):        
        conf = config.Config() # Errno 2 here
```

This is `config.py`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

CONF_FILE = "data/config.xml" 

class Config:

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = ET.parse(CONF_FILE)
        self.root = self.file.getroot()
```

And this is how I run these files in `start.py`

```
def start():
    global server_p

    server_p = subprocess.Popen('python ./server/server.py')
    md = subprocess.Popen('python ./md/md.py')
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try making the config.py file run a ls command, I think the working directory might not be the same directory that it is actually located in.

Comment: Is there a way I can dynamically get the correct path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First import `dirname` and `join` from the `os.path` module in `config.py`:

```
from os.path import dirname, join
```

Then change `CONF_FILE` to:

```
CONF_FILE = join(dirname(__file__), 'data', 'config.xml')
```

Think of `__file__` as the absolute path to the file some code is defined in, at the time it is loaded as a module. `dirname` takes that path and gives you a path to the directory that file lives in, and `join` strings together any number of arguments into a new path.

So first we would get `{abs_path_to}root/server/config.py` by reading `__file__`. Then `dirname(__file__)` gets us to `{abs_path_to}root/server`. Joining that with `data` and then `config.xml` finally gives us `{abs_path_to}root/server/data/config.xml`.

Comment: I tried to do something like that and didn't succeed, was missing the `dirname(__file__)`. Thanks for the help.